# Konjuktive II des Verbs "mitteilen" und der Satzbau

Tags: sentence-structure, conjugation

I want to be sure whether I can use Konjuktive II(Präsens) of the word "mitteilen" in the following way:

> Wenn du auch den gesamten Übungstest von diesem Aufsatz mitteilen würdest, wäre ich sehr dankbar

> Wenn du auch den gesamten Übungstest von diesem Aufsatz mitteiltest, wäre ich sehr dankbar

> Mitteiltest du den auch gesamten Übungstest von diesem Aufsatz, wäre ich sehr dankbar

I want to know

a) if the sentences above are grammatically correct

b) if yes, whether any of them would sound weird while being used in daily communication

P.S. You may totally ignore "den gesamten Übungstest von diesem Aufsatz" part, if you wish.

Comment: Not directly related to the question: Can you please clarify what _die Übungstest_ should mean? Did you mean _der Übungstext_?

Comment: I saw only the essay part, but have asked for the essay (test) exercise/question on which supposedly that writing is based on.

Comment: _Übungstest_ isn't really a (common) word in German language. And even though, it would certainly not be _feminie gender_.

Comment: Will change the gender now. I saw this word "Übungstest" from a book called "Prüfungstraining Testdaf".

Comment: Which meaning of "teilen" are you looking for: "sharing" or "dividing"?

Comment: Again, getting stuck on side issues, but I assume *Übungstest* -- "practice test" would be countable, but there's no article. Maybe *den gesamten Übungstest* instead.

Comment: Tofro, I intended to use the word "teilen" as "sharing". Could you, please, explain what difference does it make? Because as fas as I know, all the verbs in German have their Konjuktiv II form. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SterliingDanny Because "teilen" has not exactly the same connotation in German than "to share" has in English (maybe because it also has the meaning of "divide"). If you use it in the same context, it is a bit misleading and you'd better not use "teilen" at all (because it literally means "divide it in two and share the pieces" (which I hope is not what you're asking for).

Comment: @tofro Haha, will keep that in mind.  I have chosen "teilen" because I saw this verb being used on Facebook as "share" (photos, posts etc.).   Since the sentences above are addressed to a person on the internent. If it still not advised, to use "teilen" here, will replace it with mitteilen. :)

Comment: "Des Aufsatzes" wäre besser als "von diesem Aufsatz".

Comment: Danke, aber warum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)

No, they are not correct but that is because you are missing an article. Adding "den" between "auch" and "gesamten" would make each sentence correct. Apart from that, all three sentences are correct.

b)

- Sentence one is the most usual way to say it.
- Sentence two is the officially prefered but recently less common way to say it.
- Sentence three sounds somewhat archaic/dramatic and would be hard to understand for another reason too since the way it is structured would usually be used in a different context. An example for that way would be "Schenktest du mir auch die ganze Welt, wollte ich nichts mit dir zu tun haben" (Even if you would gift the entire world to me, I still would not want to have anything to do with you).

Comment: "den" is required in these sentences because it is Konjuktiv II and/or it is known what "Übungstest" is meant, right?. By the way, I really enjoyed reading your answer, thank you.

Comment: "den" is needed because "Übungstetst" is Dativ here (because "geben" requires Dativ) and not a name.

Comment: hajef ! @RDBury pointed out "den" is necessary because "Übungstetst" is countable,however,  I assume, it is a matter of choice to use article with countable nouns. For example, "den großen Tisch" or "großen Tisch" I think there is no difference, correct?

  Secondly, "etw(akk) teilen" the verb here requires accusative object, but I did not understand why you mentioned "geben" at all?

Comment: The concept of countable versus not-countable strikes me to be distinctly English. To my knowledge, it does not exist in German grammar. Also, there is usually just one way to do it right ("großen Tisch" does not go without an article) and if both are possible, they have different meanings. "Du gibst mir den Test" is not more countable than "Du gibst mir Tests" and that does not mean the same thing as "Du gibst mir die Tests". But that is a topic for a different question (and is probably already answered somewhere).

Comment: Avoidance of *würde* + infinitive for weak verbs isn't something that is commonly taught, and hasn't been for decades. Therefore, sentence one would be the "officially preferred" variant, as well as the most common one.

Comment: Apparently, I went to school before I was born. Also, the first example is called "Ersatzform", right?

Comment: Let's not be surprised by schoolteachers being out of date (in this case by decades). The first Duden grammar, from 1959, says about the *Konjunktivumschreibung*: *Die Umschreibung muß heute überall als korrekt betrachtet werden, wo die einfache Konjunktivform veraltet ist, geschraubt klingt oder mit der Indikativform
übereinstimmt.* (As cited by Martin Durrell in [this paper](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/8301/file/Durrell_Mit_der_Sprache_ging_es_immer_schon_bergab_2014.pdf)).

Comment: Google Books only has the 1966 version: https://books.google.de/books?id=tN1bAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%C3%BCberall+dort+als+korrekt%22